# TMUX: Highlight window when process finishes

Tags: tmux

I want tmux to highlight the window when process in it finishes.

Currently, I have the following settings:

```
set -g monitor-activity on
set -g visual-activity off
```

but this highlights the window when output changes, which is not very indicative for long processes with lots of logging.

How can I make it so, window is highlighted only when process is finished?

Comment: You can't, at least, not in your `tmux` settings. You can always add `; tmux send keys ...` to the end of your process so that you can do whatever you want, whether that's a tone, marking the current pane, etc.

Comment: Adding something to the end of each command is quite annoying even with an alias, do you know if there are any plans to implement something like that in future?

Comment: If it's just the typing you're worried about `PROMPT_COMMAND` would let you execute arbitrary code each time your command prompt gets printed.